# How to get the groupby nth row directly in the row as an item?

Tags: pandas

I have `Date, Time, Open, High, low, Close`, data on a minute basis of a stock. It is arranged in ascending order ( date wise ). I want to make a new column and for every day (for each row) insert the yesterday price at second row of last date). So for instance I have mentioned price of `18812.3` in front of 11th Jan since last date was `10th Jan` and its second row has a price of `18812.3`. Similarly I have done it for day before yesterday too. I tried using nth of groupby object but for I have to create a group by object. The below code is getting the a new Dataframe but I would like to create a column directly having the desired values.

```
test = bn_futures.groupby('Date')['Open','High','Low','Close'].nth(1).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please do a df.to_list() and add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try: *(check comments)*

```
# Convert Date to datetime64 and set it as index
df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)).set_index('Date')

# Find second value for each day
prices = df.groupby(level=0)['Open'].nth(1).squeeze()

# Find last row for each day
mask = ~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')

# Create new columns
df.loc[mask, 'price at yesterday'] = prices.shift(1)
df.loc[mask, 'price 2d ago'] = prices.shift(2)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            Open  price at yesterday  price 2d ago
Date                                              
2015-01-09     1                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-09     2                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-09     3                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-10     4                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-10     5                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-10     6                 2.0           NaN
2015-01-11     7                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-11     8                 NaN           NaN
2015-01-11     9                 5.0           2.0
```

Setup a MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['09-01-2015', '09-01-2015', '09-01-2015',
                            '10-01-2015', '10-01-2015', '10-01-2015',
                            '11-01-2015', '11-01-2015', '11-01-2015'],
                   'Open': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
```